# NextJS callback URL not going to different page

Tags: next.js

I am trying to navigate to a /Dashboard page that happens when the user logs in client side through gmail or github through callbackUrl but I it is giving me a 404 this page could not be found error.

Here is the project directory for the relevant files: pages.tsx is where the buttons.tsx buttons are rendered

```
ProjectName
  /app
     pages.tsx
     /components
        buttons.tsx
  /pages
     dashboard.tsx
```

Here is the code for the signin button which is located in the buttons.tsx file.

```
    return <button className="btn btn-secondary"onClick={() => signIn('google', { callbackUrl: '/Dashboard' })}>Sign in</button>;
```

And here is the dashboard.tsx code:

```
import './Dashboard.css'
import DashBoardNavbar from "../components/DashboardNavbar"



interface Props {
    children: any
}

export default function Dashboard(props: Props) {


    return (

        <div>
            
            <div className="navbar-container"> 
                <DashBoardNavbar title="Medical Reports" description="View your medical reports"> </DashBoardNavbar>
                <DashBoardNavbar title="Prescriptions" description="View your past and current prescriptions"> </DashBoardNavbar>
                <DashBoardNavbar title="Appointments" description="View your past and future appointments"> </DashBoardNavbar>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    )



}
```

I've tried changing the provider (google, undefined, etc) but that was not able to fix it. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Wouldn't the URL be `/dashboard`? [_"Each page is associated with a route based on its **file name**"_](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts)

Comment: @Phil I tried both /dashboard and /Dashboard but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Page inside App folder not in pages for example
Create a folder name dashboard then create a file page.tsx**

```
  /app
     /dashboard
         page.tsx
     pages.tsx
     /components
        buttons.tsx
```